# postgres enum with golang pgx

Tags: postgresql, go, enums, pgx

Let's say I have a micro-service in `golang` using `pgx` to connect to `postgres` database.

I have a data structure that has a enum type:

```
CREATE TYPE "direction_type" AS ENUM (
  'LEFT',
  'RIGHT',
  'UP',
  'DOWN'
);

CREATE TABLE "move_log" (
    ID uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    direction direction_type,
    steps int4
)
```

So when I try to insert a record with:

```
insertMove := "INSERT INTO move_log (id, direction, steps) values ($1, $2, $3)"
_, err := d.db.ExecContext(ctx, insertMove, uid, "LEFT", steps)
```

it fails with

```
2 UNKNOWN: ERROR: invalid input value for enum direction_type: "LEFT" (SQLSTATE 22P02)
```

I've found a pgx type [enum_array](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/v3.6.2/pgtype/enum_array.go), but I have no idea on how to use it.

- What is the correct way to work with enum in postgres using pgx in golang ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer:
https://github.com/jackc/pgx/issues/338#issuecomment-333399112

```
insertMove := "INSERT INTO move_log (id, direction, steps) values ($1, $2::text[]::direction_type[], $3)"
```

Works.